# Solving 'n' equtions simultaneously in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have equations of the form `alpha*xf + beta*xb = xm` where *xf*, *xb* and *xm* are values from 3 separate lists. I want to solve them in Mathematica simultaneously for *alpha* and *beta* by taking in successive values for *xf*, *xb* and *xm*. *I.e*, in the first step I solve for *i* and *i*+1 values of *xf*, *xb* and *xm*, next I solve for *i*+1 and *i*+2 values of *xf*, *xb* and *xm*.

Comment: It's not at all clear what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess of what he is looking for

```
(*Make up some example data*)
{xflist, xblist, xmlist} = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {3, 4}];

(*Split each list into {{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}...}*)
xfl = Partition[xflist, 2, 1];
xbl = Partition[xblist, 2, 1];
xml = Partition[xmlist, 2, 1];

(*Solve two equations with two unknowns given six parameters*)
mysolve[{xf1_, xf2_}, {xb1_, xb2_}, {xm1_, xm2_}] := {alpha, beta} /. 
Solve[{alpha*xf1+beta*xb1==xm1, alpha*xf2+beta*xb2==xm2}, {alpha,beta}][[1]];

(*Use that to Solve for alpha and beta for all the sets of parameters*)
MapThread[mysolve, {xfl, xbl, xml}]
```